# Decrypting code from two lists

Tags: python

I think I have the right idea to solve this function, but I'm not sure why I don't get the desired result. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
>>>decrypt(['a', '2', 's', 'c', '0'], [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4])

My output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]


>>>decrypt(['a', '2', 's', 'c', '0'], [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4])

Desired Output: ['c', 's', 'c', 'a', '2', '0']


def decrypt(characters, code):
    L = []
    for item in range(len(characters)):
        result = characters[item]
        answer = code.index(item)
        L.append(item)
    return L
```

Comment: don't know what u want, but result & answer ? where they use? range(5) ----> L.append(0 .... 4 ), so print L => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 1):

if you want characters - source, code - get char from source order

```
def decrypt(characters, code):
    L = []
    for item in range(len(code)):
        result = code[item]
        L.append(characters[result])
    return L 

print(decrypt(['a', '2', 's', 'c', '0'], [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is your `item` variable is the number counting `0,1,2,3,4`... for the indices of the `code` list. Instead, you should iterate over the integers that make up `code` by doing `in code:` instead of `in range(...`. That way, `item` is the values of code on each item of the list, which are the indices that you want to get out of `characters`.

```
def decrypt(characters, code):
    L = []
    for item in code:
        result = characters[item]
        L.append(result)
    return L

print(decrypt(['a', '2', 's', 'c', '0'], [3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]))
```

This could also be done with a list comprehension:

```
def decrypt(characters,code):
    return [characters[i] for i in code]
```

Comment: How could I do this looping through characters?

Comment: Why do you think you need to loop through characters? Characters is just a container storing your values, but `code` is your key to look things up. Looping through characters won't do anything useful. Try the code I listed, and toy with it so that you understand how it works and why it works.

Comment: I didn't look at your second answer. I deleted my answer ignoring 1 upvote.